# Casting String to Long in Jasper report

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am trying to convert a String value to long in jasper report and convert it to Date object. But i always end up getting a class cast exception from String to Long.

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
```

I am trying following code

```
<variable name="date" class="java.util.Date">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Date(Long.getLong($F{field}))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Long.getLong(String s) gives desired output in Java. But when we use same java expression it gives exception in jasper. Does jasper treats primitive java types differently?

**EDIT**: Complete stack trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number
    at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillTimeSeries.evaluate(JRFillTimeSeries.java:147)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.charts.fill.JRFillTimeSeriesDataset.customEvaluate(JRFillTimeSeriesDataset.java:104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementDataset.evaluate(JRFillElementDataset.java:155)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.calculateVariables(JRCalculator.java:160)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:765)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:864)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:569)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:915)
    at NwLogCollector.main(MyExp.java:682)
```

Comment: try `Long.parseLong()`

Comment: Doesn't work. Tried all types of conversions :/

Comment: try `Long.valueOf()` (once :) ), I assume you are recompiling jrxml eachtime

Comment: Nope valueOf doesn't work. Yes recompiling jrxml everytime

Answer (score 1):

[`Long.getLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#getLong%28java.lang.String%29) fetches a *system property* with the given name, and parses that to a `Long`. I very much doubt that that's the behaviour you want.

You probably want [`Long.parseLong`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong%28java.lang.String%29) or [`Long.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29). However, be aware that these are both quite strict - if your string has spaces in or anything similar, you'll need to trim it first.

If that still doesn't work, I suggest you add a diagnostic log of `$F{field}` to show *exactly* what it's trying to parse first.

EDIT: I wouldn't expect a `ClassCastException` in the code you've given anyway. I suspect something else is going wrong before it tries to parse the value - but when you *have* got past that, you'll need to change from `Long.getLong` to `Long.parseLong` anyway.

Comment: Nope. While filling the jasper report i get same exception for all 3 formats of conversion. parseLong, valueOf and getLong

Comment: @DheerajJoshi: If you're getting the *same* exception, then I doubt that it's even getting as far as parsing. Please post the *full exception stack trace* in your question.

Comment: @Dheeraj Are you compiling jrxml to .jasper after modification ? (I would suggest delete generated .jasper files and let it recompile)

Comment: compiling jrxml to jasper is fine. Problem comes while filling.

Comment: @DheerajJoshi: Can you create a short but complete report which *just* shows this problem? It looks to me like the problem isn't really in `Long.getLong` itself...

Comment: You mean with fields and time series chart band?

Comment: @Dheeraj he meant a simple minimal example to reproduce your issue, you try with that first and if it fails post your minimal jrxml

Answer (score 0):

You must use Long.parseLong() not getLong() method, because parsing from String to Long value is what parseLong() method does.

Check this Javadoc for complete reference
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Solved. Had to look at the jasper internal code to make the changes.
Problem was not while converting date. It was somewhere else

Comment: you should probably close the question then, or accept this answer.

Comment: Accept my answer as answer? Well my original question itself is not valid as problem was somewhere else. so

Comment: Well you should do something to "close" the question. Maybe edit it to say "solved" of similar.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem in the report filling with String to BigDecimal ClassCastException, can you give me some hint about your findings?